# Upgrade Magento 2.2.0 to 2.2.5 giving problems

Tags: magento2

Please advise. Thanks

After doing this:

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update
composer update
authenticate correctly for repo.magento.com

I get this error:

> [u9945p7191@web0102 public_html]$ Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
>   [u9945p7191@web0102 public_html]$ https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   -bash: https://repo.magento.com: No such file or directory
>   [u9945p7191@web0102 public_html]$ Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [u9945p7191@web0102 public_html]$ Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.2.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.1, 2.0.10, 2.1.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you may use wrong key-pair for upgradation, you have to use the pair which you have used previously in installation.

I think this may be an error of **proxy** or **firewall** restriction. I had the similar one and i used the following workaround for it.

> set proxy

```
export https_proxy='192.168.10.5:8080'
export http_proxy='192.168.10.5:8080'
```